# Drupal node update detection

Tags: javascript, updating

Can anyone suggest how I might detect when a node has been updated via jquery?

I know jquery is a client-side technology but I really need to utilize jquery(ajax) to alert my users when a node is updated.

Comment: Do you mean a particular node or any node? The latter will be pretty tricky but not impossible

Answer (score 1):

In the classic [HTTP](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/HTTP) model, the server is passive and can only return information to the client when it request it. So, in this model, to alert the users when a node is updated, you have to periodically poll the server the ask it if the node has been updated. If you have a lot of clients waiting for the update of a lot of nodes, this can quickly overload your web server with too much request to handle.

Today, the best solution for this kind of requirements is to use [WebSockets](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/WebSocket) or a similar [full-duplex](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Duplex_%28telecommunications%29#Full-duplex) technologies. Drupal and PHP are not designed to serve a WebSockets. Technologies like [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/),  or [APE](http://www.ape-project.org/) are more suited.

The [Node.js integration](https://drupal.org/project/nodejs) module integrates node.js and Socket.IO in a easy to use solution. It provides an API to easily implements your need.